# extract strings pattern from file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

i want to extract strings patterns from a file . My input file looks like this :

```
Name = Apple Is Red
Hidden = True
Name = Banana Is Yellow
Hidden = False
Name = Orange Is Orange
Hidden = True
Name = Guava Is Green
Hidden = False
```

What i want in the output is it will create two files one with true.log & false.log :

`true.log`

```
Name = Apple is Red
Hidden = True
Name = Orange Is Orange
Hidden = True
```

`false.log`

```
Name = Banana Is Yellow
Hidden = False
Name = Guava Is Green
Hidden = False
```

New at bash scripting and Linux .

Comment: Name = blah blah (line break)
Hidden = True (line break)
Name = foo foo (line break)
Hidden = False (line break)

file is in this format

Answer (score 0):

Simple `grep` with `-B` (before context)

```
grep -B1 --no-group-separator 'Hidden = True' myfile
```

(`--no-group-separator` so there is no superfluous hyphens)

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
apple=$(cut inputfile -d"=" -f2) #what stands after the = into a variable apple
if [ $apple = "Apple Is Red" ] ; then
    echo "Hidden = true" >> true.txt
fi
```

Edit: sry my connection hang up

Comment: it doesn't worked dude